# Method missing error when running vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

My development environment relies on vagrant and virtual box. Everything used to work until a few days ago. Since then, every time I try to run `vagrant up`, I'm getting this error message.

I don't really know what to do about it. Any advice?

```
C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:90:in `method_missing': undefined method `run_remote=' for #<VagrantPlugins::Triggers::DSL:0x00000000049cb5b8> (NoMethodError)
        from D:/Projects/D3TzH/D3TzH-environment/Vagrantfile:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:11:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/dsl.rb:11:in `fire!'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:52:in `block in fire_triggers'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:51:in `each'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:51:in `fire_triggers'
        from C:/Users/D3TzH/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.4/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/before_trigger.rb:23:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:102:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:102:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:238:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:209:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:615:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:195:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:195:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Comment: The Vagrant triggers plugin provided functionality that was included in core Vagrant as of 2.1.0 released long ago. That plugin became incompatible afterwards. Try uninstalling that plugin and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard if you make this an actual post, I can accept it as a solution. Your comment fixed my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of Vagrant 2.1.0, the functionality of the `vagrant-triggers` plugin was incorporated into the core Vagrant product. As noted in the [Vagrant 2.1.0 announcement](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-vagrant-2-1-0/), the plugin is now incompatible with versions of Vagrant >= 2.1.0:

> This work was heavily inspired by the fantastic community plugin vagrant-triggers by @emyl. It is a complete rewrite of the plugin, so the two are not compatible.

Given that situation, the error is most likely fixed by uninstalling the third party `vagrant-triggers` plugin.